# Can different parts of streched massless string have different accelerations such that the string remains streched?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Here is the picture of the actual question. Here how is it possible that the string on pulley 2 has different accelerations but is still taut? I didn't understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, string on pulley 2 will have same acceleration and tension throughout its length. There is no possible way for a string to exert force in slack condition also a single piece of string cant have different tensions- it will have same tension force throughout its length.

Coming back to your question, constant velocity means that the object does not have any acceleration.

Since $M_2$ is has more mass then $M_1$ therefore $M_2$ will move in downward direction with some acceleration and $M_1$ will go in upward direction with same acceleration.
You can calculate the tension in the string and their acceleration using simple equations. With the above motion ongoing on pulley 2, the whole setup will also be accelerating in downward direction due to pulley 1. So overall $M_1$ has two accelerations one is due to arrangement on pulley 2 - in upward direction and other is due to pulley 1 - in downward direction. For $M_2$ both accelerations are in downward direction. So for resultant motion as observed from ground, these two acceleration vectors (each) should be added for the two masses.

For $M_1$ to have constant velocity i.e. zero acceleration, sum of accelerations due to pulley 1 and 2 should be zero.

Evaluate the above condition and you will get your answer.
Comment if your have any doubt in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

> Here how is it possible that the string on pulley 2 has different accelerations but is still taut?

Your intuition is likely telling you that the string on pulley 2 will have equal acceleration magnitudes throughout its length relative to pulley 2 if it is to remain taught. Your intuition would be correct if that is in fact where it guides you. Despite this, if pulley 2 itself moves downwards the acceleration of the two masses attached the the string on pulley 2 need not be equal relative to a frame of reference affixed to the surface the large "M" is sitting on. In fact, if you construct a free body diagram you will see that the acceleration of m1 will always be zero if the tension in the string around pulley 2 is equal to the weight of m1. This is all to say that your confusion about the question is caused by your choice of reference frame. Relative to the surface in the figure, m1 and m2 can have different speeds and accelerations.

Comment: But here the surface on which M is sitting isn't the same as ground frame of reference?

Comment: The distinction between the ground frame of reference and the frame of reference defined by the surface mass M is sitting on makes no difference because those two reference frames don't move relative to each other. You can choose either one of those two and be successful.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine for a moment that rather than just letting everything move under gravity, you hold a few things stationary.  Lets fix $M$ and $m_2$ in place.

Both pulleys are free to rotate, but by holding those masses still, nothing can move.  All masses have $v = 0$.

Now, while keeping $m_2$ in place, apply a force strong enough to pull $M$ to the left.  What happens with the two smaller masses?

Since $m_2$ is fixed, it has zero acceleration.  But if the rope does not stretch, then $m_1$ must move upward.  So it has undergone acceleration.

So the motion of the string across pulley 2 can give $m_1$ and $m_2$ different velocities and accelerations.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me in imagining correctly!